# Add the decimals and align to the right

Tags: awk, text-formatting, numeric-data

Trying to re-format a column, but I need to add decimals to the price and need to be align to the right. It also needs leading white spaces at end in order to work with other column.

```
awk -F, '{print $6}' $FILE | awk '{printf("%-7s\n", $0) }' > $TEMP/unit_price
```

current output:

```
99
121.5
108
67.5
```

This is how I need it to look like and align to the right:

```
  99.00
  63.00
 121.50
 108.00
 108.00
  67.50
 67.50
```

Comment: You probably want a format specifier like `%7.2f` rather than `%-7s`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- 1 awk is enough for all your treatment
- `%s` convert your number to a string basically, use another format converter like `%f` for float in this case

  ```
  awk -F ',' '{printf("%3.2f\n", $6}' ${FILE} > ${TEMP}/unit_price
  ```